# MIPS Assembly why are these registers loading the same array values?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I'm trying to load in array values in the first and second position but for some reason it's loading in only the value in the first position?  Been trying to figure it out for an hour but no luck.  This is the code I have.  I set $t1 to 0 and $t3 to 4 so I should be loading in the first and second value, yet it only loads in the first value for both $t1 and $t3?

```
 addi $t1, $zero, 0 
 addi $t3, $zero, 4
 
 
 
 FindLessThenLoop:
 la $t1, myArray # Load first number
 addu $t1, $zero, $t1 # add offset and base together
 lw $t1, ($t1)      # fetch the data 
 
 la $t3, myArray # Load second number
 addu $t3, $zero, $t3 # add offset and base together
 lw $t3, ($t3)      # fetch the data
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for the first and the second are essentially the same except using a different register, so, we would expect the same results: the value from array position/index 0.

To get the second element, you can do either:

```
la $t3, myArray     # Load second number
addiu $t3, $t3, 4   # add offset and base together
lw $t3, ($t3)       # fetch the data
```

-or-

```
la $t3, myArray     # Load second number
lw $t3, 4($t3)      # fetch the data with offset 4
```

You'll prefer a variation of the first form if you're going to do variable indexing (e.g. a[i]), say in a loop, whereas the second form is for constant indexing (e.g. a[1]).

If you have an integer index, then the following is useful:

```
# usually done outside of and before a loop:
la $t3, myArray     # Load second number

# this part done inside a loop:
sll $t4, $t2, 2     # scale the integer index by 4
addu $t4, $t3, $t4  # add base and offset
lw $t1, ($t4)       # fetch the data
```

Note the following:

1. there is pre-loop setup of `$t3`
2. inside the loop we preserve `$t3` so it can be used each iteration
3. we scale the simple integer index by size of the elements (4x)

---

An alternative is pointers, which are fairly easy in assembly, but suggest to convert your algorithm to pointers in C first, then take to assembly.

A pointer combines into one variable the notion of base + scaled offset.  A pointer can be incremented to refer to the next element.

---

Here's a simple illustrative loop that does max value of array, assuming elements are positive:

```
    li $t0, array # t0 is the base array address: &array[0]
    li $t1, 0     # t1 is min value variable, initially zero
    li $t2, 0     # t2 is the index, aka loop control variable call it "i"
    li $t3, 10    # where to stop with "i"

loop1:
    beq $t2, $t3, loop1End   # if "i" == 10 we're done

    sll $t4, $t2, 2          # scale index by 4 due to word-sized elements
    add $t4, $t0, $t4        # add base and scaled offset
    lw $t4, 0($t4)           # fetch element from a[i]

    ble $t4, $t1, if1End
    move $t1, $t4            # capture the new max, if larger
if1End:

    addi $t2, $t2, 1         # next index position
    j loop1

loop1End:
    ...                      # t1 holds max value from the array
```

Comment: So I need $t1 and $t3 to continually hop to the next position.  Because I am comparing the first number and the second number to find the smallest of the two, then I continue on until the user enters 0 to stop.  The issue with the addiu and adding 4 is that it will continue to stay in the second position?

Comment: Yes, sometimes you need two different variables for indexes, like i, and j, so you can refer to different elements.  The `addiu` is only offset by constant, which you can also do using the offset in the addressing mode, e.g. 4($s0), but if you are doing variable indexing need the `addu` form and potentially the `sll` to scale the index. Array indexing is a small series of operations, where you scale the index, then add to the base, then dereference, via load or store.  The offset built into the addressing mode often doesn't help when doing variable indexing.  (But can help with `a[i+1]`.)

Comment: Though not strictly necessary, I suggest to work out the algorithm in C first, then take it to assembly knowing how array indexing works.

Comment: See my edit illustrating a simple loop with array indexing.  You can do nested loops or sequential loops and more as needed.  Each construct in C has an equivalent in assembly.

Comment: Thank you!  I will go over this.  I also just added the code I currently have, everything is working besides it's not moving onto the next variable in the array.  In the SetLessThenFirst: and SetLessThenSecond: I am trying to add 4 to each so it grabs the next variable.   That's not working and also when I load word in FindLessThenLoop it is adding the same value to each variable.  So I have a lot of troubleshooting to do still....

Comment: could you maybe check out the code I put and tell me where I'm going wrong?  As far as how to go through the whole array and load in the first and second values properly?

Comment: Try it in C first.  It is very hard to think algorithmically in assembly when you don't know it.  The C version will make it clear what you're trying to accomplish; knowing that is vital to what you're doing in assembly, so that will make it easier!

Comment: You are using pointers instead of variable array indexing, which is fine.  But your loop structure is only comparing a[i] with a[i+1] ever.  Is that what you want?  Without seeing the pseudo code for what you're trying to do, it is hard to say.

Comment: I haven't worked with C before, there is an easy way to convert C code?  Also I have the full code posted now.  So what I am trying to do is allow a user to enter up to 8 numbers, then compare all these numbers in this array to find the smallest number and output it.

Comment: Ok, try it in Java then, or do a search for a min algorithm.  The way min is done is to compare each element in the array to the lowest known value so far, using only one index or pointer, rather than using two pointers.  It is difficult to write an algorithm in assembly when you don't know either the algorithm or assembly language.  So, make it easier by doing solving it in a language you know, then take that to assembly.